# ICollectionView filtering issue

Tags: wpf, filter, collectionview

i'm having a ICollectionView with filtering in colde.
the problem is that the filtering never executes...

this is the code:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _jobSizes;
private CollectionViewSource _jobSizesSource;


public ICollectionView JobSizesView
{
    get
    {
        if (_jobSizesSource == null)
        {
            _jobSizesSource = new CollectionViewSource
                {
                    Source = JobSizes
                };
        }

        _jobSizesSource.View.Filter = OnSizeFilter;
        return _jobSizesSource.View;
    }
}


private bool OnSizeFilter(object item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_size))
        return true;

    if (((string) item).StartsWith(Size))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

i use JobSizesView.Refresh(); 
to refresh the list... but also while constructing the list the filter is not executes...

Comment: i tried this...just copy pasted this code and it worked

Comment: If _jobSizes/JobSizes isn't null it works for me too.

Comment: correct.
i didn't populate the collection for the viewcollectionsource.
and it smart enough not to try filter an empty collection...